Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'
I'm trying to start my Angular project, but I'm encountering an error:
Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'.
Screenshot 1

Screenshot 2

Configuration Files: angular.json
Screenshot 3

and this is package.json
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
        "@angular/common": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/core": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.7",
        "@angular/router": "~11.2.7",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
        "angular-datatables": "^11.2.0",
        "angular2-tag-input": "^1.2.3",
        "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
        "c": "^1.1.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.7.0",
        "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.7.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "nanoid": "^3.1.23",
        "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
        "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^4.0.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.6.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
        "sweetalert2": "^10.16.7",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.6",
        "@angular/cli": "~11.2.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.7",
        "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
        "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.5",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.1.5"
      }
    }

Here are the outputs of my ng version and nvm list.
Screenshot 4

Screenshot 5

Looking forward to suggestions on how to resolve this issue!
this is the import



try deleting .angular, node_modules and package-lock.json and then do a install and run npm run start

I don't see any screenshots mentioned import DataTables error.

what do you mean by .angular

@ChaymaeLOUKILI It's a folder located in the same folder as package.json of your project, it contains the angular cache

i have add the screen for imort
the errors i have in the files are this errors
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pagingType' does not exist in type 'Settings'.ts(2353)
(property) pagingType: string
No quick fixes available
Property 'search' does not exist on type 'Api'.ts(2339)
any
Property 'destroy' does not exist on type 'Api'.ts(2339)
